# Reading CSV file into Dataset WITHOUT headers

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv

I have a small problem with the following code. The code works fine if I don't include HDR=NO.
The CSV that will be used for this WEB app will not have any header info.
How can I read it into a dataset and create static column names?

I get this error when running the code below:
**Could not find installable ISAM.**

Here is my code so far:

```
FileUpload1.SaveAs(System.IO.Path.Combine(target, FileUpload1.FileName));

string connString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=Text; HDR=NO;", System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(target + "\\" + FileUpload1.FileName));
string cmdString = string.Format("SELECT * FROM {0}", System.IO.Path.GetFileName(target + "\\" + FileUpload1.FileName));

OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmdString, connString);
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);

GridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0];
GridView1.DataBind();
```

I would appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `Extended Properties=Text; HDR=NO;` change to `Extended Properties=""text;HDR=No""` or              `Extended Properties=\"text;HDR=No\"`.

This error is generated when the syntax of the connection string is incorrect. This commonly occurs when using multiple Extended Properties parameters.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick answer but the my life of it I don't seem to be able to modify this code without errors"string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=Text;", System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(target + "\\" + FileUpload1.FileName));